# Why is Safari ignoring my CSS position?

Tags: css, safari

The problem is on this page: http://www.matternow.com/portfolio/

If you click on any of the thumbnails you'll see that the image title in the lower left of the overlay is too close to the border above it. This looks fine in Chrome (and all the other browsers, for that matter). Seems like it's ignoring my CSS for the element, which is set to be bottom: 0;

This is a browser hack, by the way. Looks like This:

```
#portfolio-overlay #cboxTitle{
        font: bold 21px 'Crimson Text', serif !important;
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        top: auto;
        left: 10px;
        color:#000;
    }

@media screen and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    #portfolio-overlay #cboxTitle {
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Anyone know why this is happening? I mean, since it looks good in Chrome it SHOULD look good in Safari, right?

Comment: Does Safari understand `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't follow why you require the hack. Why can't you just set the original value as 0?

Regardless, you're missing the space after the 'and' in your media query. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#syntax example #20